# error display when I run 'cordova run android' command

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, build, visual-studio-cordova

**I'm developing an app for android using cordova and when I put the command 'cordova run android' it gives me this error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.tools.apk.analyzer.ApkAnalyzerCli.getAaptInvokerFromSdk(ApkAnalyzerCli.java:277)
        at com.android.tools.apk.analyzer.ApkAnalyzerCli.main(ApkAnalyzerCli.java:129)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 5 more
```

**I was hoping to see**

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Android\sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Android\sdk
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s
50 actionable tasks: 50 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s): 
    C:\apps\alpha-assistente\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
    Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
    ANDROID_HOME=C:\Android\sdk (recommended setting)
    ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (DEPRECATED)
    Using Android SDK: C:\Android\sdk
```